# How much does a health regen pack decrease the regeneration delay?

Tags: tribes-ascend

Normally, your health begins to regenerate after not taking any damage for 15 seconds. The description of the Juggernaut class' Health Regen Pack says it decreases this time, but it doesn't say *by how much*.

So: When I'm using this pack, how long do I have to wait before I start regenerating health, and how many more seconds does each upgrade (-3%/level) shave off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each upgrade reduces the time to start regenerating by 3%, so:

- No Health Regen Pack: 15.00 s
- Level 1: 14.55 s
- Level 2: 14.10 s
- Level 3: 13.65 s

Comment: So the pack doesn't do *anything* until I upgrade it at least once?

Comment: By "Level 0", I meant with no Health Regen Pack at all. I'll make that clearer.